# Find all circular path that contains only unique path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following code to initiate the database

```
create
(C1: Company{name:'Company A'}),  
(C2: Company{name:'Company B'}), 
(C3: Company{name:'Company C'}),
(C4: Company{name:'Company D'}),
(C1)-[:Sell{contract:"TA1801"}]->(C2),
(C2)-[:Sell{contract:"TA1802"}]->(C3),
(C3)-[:Sell{contract:"TA1803"}]->(C1),
(C3)-[:Sell{contract:"TA1804"}]->(C4),
(C1)-[:Sell{contract:"TA1805"}]->(C4),
(C4)-[:Sell{contract:"TA1806"}]->(C1)
```

Let's say I would like to find only the unique path for "Company A"

```
MATCH path = (start:Company{name:"Company A"})-[r:Sell*]->(end:Company{name:"Company A"})
RETURN  path
```

It returns five path

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path"                                                                │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1805"},{"name":"Company D"},{"nam│
│e":"Company D"},{"contract":"TA1806"},{"name":"Company A"}]           │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1805"},{"name":"Company D"},{"nam│
│e":"Company D"},{"contract":"TA1806"},{"name":"Company A"},{"name":"Co│
│mpany A"},{"contract":"TA1801"},{"name":"Company B"},{"name":"Company │
│B"},{"contract":"TA1802"},{"name":"Company C"},{"name":"Company C"},{"│
│contract":"TA1803"},{"name":"Company A"}]                             │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1801"},{"name":"Company B"},{"nam│
│e":"Company B"},{"contract":"TA1802"},{"name":"Company C"},{"name":"Co│
│mpany C"},{"contract":"TA1803"},{"name":"Company A"}]                 │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1801"},{"name":"Company B"},{"nam│
│e":"Company B"},{"contract":"TA1802"},{"name":"Company C"},{"name":"Co│
│mpany C"},{"contract":"TA1803"},{"name":"Company A"},{"name":"Company │
│A"},{"contract":"TA1805"},{"name":"Company D"},{"name":"Company D"},{"│
│contract":"TA1806"},{"name":"Company A"}]                             │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1801"},{"name":"Company B"},{"nam│
│e":"Company B"},{"contract":"TA1802"},{"name":"Company C"},{"name":"Co│
│mpany C"},{"contract":"TA1804"},{"name":"Company D"},{"name":"Company │
│D"},{"contract":"TA1806"},{"name":"Company A"}]                       │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

However you can see the relation sell with a contract of TA1806,TA1801,TA1802 is being repeated more than once. 
A specific example will be TA1806 appeared in route 1,2,4 and 5.  TA1801 appeared in route 2,3,4,5

What i hope that the path contain only unique relation with the shortest path (initially i wanted the longest, but it seems that the complexity increase alot )

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path"                                                                │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1805"},{"name":"Company D"},{"nam│
│e":"Company D"},{"contract":"TA1806"},{"name":"Company A"}]           │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤┤
│[{"name":"Company A"},{"contract":"TA1801"},{"name":"Company B"},{"nam│
│e":"Company B"},{"contract":"TA1802"},{"name":"Company C"},{"name":"Co│
│mpany C"},{"contract":"TA1803"},{"name":"Company A"}]                 │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

Comment: How would you decide which path to choose? Shortest path?

Comment: I wanted the longest path, but i don't want to ask two questions at a go, that's why i did not state it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `Do you have any suggestions?` I would not be surprised now that you have identified the result you want as the `longest` instead of `unique` that someone much more adept at Cypher should be able to answer this.

Comment: You noted in the comment that you wanted the longest path  which is `A -TA1801-> B -TA1802 -> C - TA1804-> D- TA1806 ->A` but in your question you said you wanted `A -TA1801-> B -TA1802 -> C - TA1803 -> A` which is not the longest. Maybe you should clarify your question more.

Comment: Most of the time when I want to ask a question here I do research and pretend to explain it to someone who does not know the topic. In so doing, many times I find the answer on my own. It may take hours, days, or even weeks, but is worth the effort. Also I keep extensive notes that help out. I don't always remember exactly what was in my notes, but I almost always remember the general idea because I reinforced my learning by creating notes. Same here with comments; it reinforces the Q&A I find of value.

Comment: edited though. thanks though. I'll try to solve the solution and post it here. Will do more research

Comment: You might also want to change the title as it still has the word unique.

Comment: the unique is kinda required though. As There might be multiple circular path that starts from A and ends at A, I'll update the example to include a more detailed description. Thanks  for the headup!

Comment: By default, Cypher will never repeat the same relationship in a path. The reason you're seeing a single path with multiple relationships for `TA1806` is because in your create query you've created two separate relationships with this same contract value between the same two nodes, one incoming and one outgoing. I'm guessing one of these is supposed to be `TA805`?

Comment: yeah, edited the question. What i meant was for the relationship not to appear in any other route that is returned

Comment: Keep in mind that this new requirement interferes with the ability to consistently and correctly find the longest path. If we use RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL uniqueness (a rel can only be used in a single path), and if an earlier shorter path finds a node that could be in a longer path, then those relationships have been exhausted early and can't be used in the longer path. I think you may want to spend some time thinking over what you really want here and then making sure you clearly communicate it, complete with full examples with example input and output.

Answer (score 5):

For longest path you can just order the paths by length and take the longest, but APOC helps for the duplication check (excepting the start node, since you want a circuit):

```
MATCH path = (start:Company{name:"Company A"})-[r:Sell*]->(end:Company{name:"Company A"})
WHERE NOT apoc.coll.containsDuplicates(tail(nodes(path)))
WITH path
ORDER BY length(path) DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN path
```

The pure-Cypher approach for not repeating nodes in the path is rather ugly:

```
MATCH path = (start:Company{name:"Company A"})-[r:Sell*]->(end:Company{name:"Company A"})
    WHERE all(node in tail(nodes(path)) WHERE single(x in tail(nodes(path)) WHERE x = node))
    WITH path
    ORDER BY length(path) DESC
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN path
```

Comment: Hmm. What i needed is kinda not repeating relationship. From the example, the :Sell property with the same same contract, such as TA1801,TA1802 ,TA1806 is being repeated more than once. 

Or should i model my relationship into node instead

Comment: edited the question! thanks for your initial answer, very much appreciated.